# Inserting character into variable names

Tags: r, regex, string

I have a dataset with variable names such as `FamId00` and `ISCO8899` and would like to write a command to insert an underscore before the last two digits, which represent years. What is the best way of doing it? I have tried with `regex` but the further I got was to:

`gsub('.{2}$', '', varname)`

which gives me:

`FamId`

How to I add `'_'` and the original last two digits back? Also, I have variables in the dataset that do not have the year in the last two digits (i.e. `ID` and `sex`). Is there a way to keep the regular expression from affecting those?

Comment: Depending on the data, you might even need `sub("(?<!_)(\\d{2})$", "_\\1", varname, perl=TRUE)` or `sub("(^|[^_])([0-9]{2})$", "\\1_\\2", varname)`.

Comment: I see that this was marked as a duplicate. Shall I delete this question?

Comment: You do not have to delete questions if they are marked as duplicates. It is up to you.

Comment: @Kenji It is better to keep dupe questions because it will be easier to google and find the posts when somebody searches next time

Comment: Oh well, but then what is the point of flagging it and downvoting? I'll leave it around then...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We don't need `gsub` just a `sub` would be enough as this is only a single instance replacement.  Capture the last two characters as a group (`(...)`) and in the replacement use the `_` followed by the backreference of that capture group

```
sub("(.{2})$", "_\\1", varname)
#[1] "FamId_00"  "ISCO88_99"
```

The `.` is a metacharacter implying any character.  If this needs to be specific i.e. digits, use `\\d{2}` in place of `.{2}`

#### data

```
varname <- c("FamId00", "ISCO8899")
```

Comment: This does it. It seems so simple in hindsight that I can't believe I didn't find this answer elsewhere.

Comment: Also, is there a way to keep it from doing this to variables that don't have number in the last two digits?

Comment: @Kenji If you meant to have only replacement for numbers, then `sub("(\\d{2})$", "_\\1", varname)`

Answer (score 0):

Alternative solution always using `sub()` or `gsub()` and a different pattern.

```
ids <- c("FamId00", "ISCO8899")
gsub("(^.*)([[:digit:]]{2}$)", "\\1_\\2", ids)
[1] "FamId_00"  "ISCO88_99"
```